# Vim 8.1 on Windows 10 Won't Detect Packages in $HOME

Tags: microsoft-windows, packages

Take a plugin like [Flake8](https://github.com/nvie/vim-flake8). It instructs users to install using Vim 8's package manager by:

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/pack/flake8/start/
cd ~/.vim/pack/flake8/start/
git clone https://github.com/nvie/vim-flake8.git
```

On Windows, this brings up some questions about the compatibility of these paths. What is `~` here? Should the files actually go in `~/.vim`, or should they go in the Windows equivalent - `~/vimfiles`?

You can answer these questions by:

1. Using `:echo expand('~')` and `:echo $HOME` to learn what `~` and `$HOME` mean.
2. Using `:set packpath` to show your packpath.

These are the answers I get on my copy of Windows 10, with a fresh install of Vim 8.1:

```
:set packpath
```

> packpath=~/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program
>   Files (x86) \Vim\vim81,C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after,~/vimfiles/after

```
:echo expand('~')
```

> C:\Users\user.name

```
:echo $HOME
```

> C:\Users\user.name

From those answers, it seems like the place to make the `pack/*/start` directories is in `C:\Users\user.name\vimfiles`.

However, that doesn't work! If I put the Flake8 files in `C:\Users\user.name\vimfiles\pack\flake8\start`, they don't get automatically loaded. And this problem doesn't seem to be with just with Flake8 - this doesn't work with any plugin I've tried.

Looking at `:scriptnames`, the only scripts that are picked up are in `C:\Program Files (x86)`. Nothing in `~`.

Note that there is no `_vimrc` or `.vimrc` file in `~` or `~/vimfiles` or `~/.vim` at this time.

I can verify that Flake8 works just fine if it's sourced manually, like so:

```
:source ~\vimfiles\pack\flake8\start\autoload\flake8.vim
:source ~\vimfiles\pack\flake8\start\ftplugin\python_flake8.vim
```

Is it possible to use the Vim 8 package manager on a per-user basis when Vim is running on Windows? If it is, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Excellent detailed question! You happened to include the bit that exposed the issue you're likely having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bit you quoted about sourcing the files manually gave it away:

> I can verify that Flake8 works just fine if it's sourced manually, like so:
>
> ```
> :source ~\vimfiles\pack\flake8\start\autoload\flake8.vim
> :source ~\vimfiles\pack\flake8\start\ftplugin\python_flake8.vim
> ```

You need to have a **plug-in directory** under `start/` and the plug-in contents inside that directory.

In your case, you should have a `vim-flake8/` under `start/` and `autoload/` and `ftplugin/` under that subdirectory:

```
~\vimfiles\pack\flake8\start\vim-flake8\autoload\flake8.vim
~\vimfiles\pack\flake8\start\vim-flake8\ftplugin\python_flake8.vim
```

If you follow the `git clone` instructions you referred to (adapting to `~/vimfiles`), you should end up with a tree such as this one here.

Comment: Thank you! I missed that when I got caught up in the difference between `~/.vim` and `~\vimfiles`.

Comment: I find that while `vim` in Powershell can find these plugins, when `vim` is launched from `git` like `git rebase -i ...` it doesn't find the relevant plugins anymore.